# Algorithms for finding number of sequences with length N and displacements less than k

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

The sequences are made up of only digits. A displacement is defined as pair $(i, j)$ such that $i > j$ and $A[i] < A[j]$. For example, 423 has 2 displacements.

The question is to find the number of sequences of length $N$ such that number of displacements is less than a given $k$ in $O(n^2)$.

The only given hint is that this is a DP problem. I could not find a way to turn this to a recursive problem. Is there a way to turn this into another DP problem?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?